# R - Combine two data sets without duplicates and return the value its comparing for one comparison, and zero for remaining NA's

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, compare

I've been trying to merge / join the following two sample data sets to get a combination of each name and season while retaining the value and not returning duplicates or extra columns.

```
#Data1
df1 <- data.frame(name = c("Jose","Tom","Mike","Justin","Fred"), 
  season = c("fall", "fall", "fall","fall","fall"),
  value = c("1","2","3","4","5"))
df1

#Data2
df2 <- data.frame(name = c("Jose", "Tom", "Ben","Justin","Mike"), 
  season = c("spring", "spring","spring","spring","spring"),
  value = c("6","7","8","9","10"))
df2

dfcomb <- merge(df1,df2,by="name",all=TRUE)


> dfcomb
    name season.x value.x season.y value.y
1    Ben     <NA>    <NA>   spring       8
2   Fred     fall       5     <NA>    <NA>
3   Jose     fall       1   spring       6
4 Justin     fall       4   spring       9
5   Mike     fall       3   spring      10
6    Tom     fall       2   spring       7
```

But if I would like for the result to be for season to fill in the NA according to the missing season and for the value in the other NA to be 0, how would I do this? Then ideally, I'd like for it just be displayed in three columns, name, season, and value.

```
     name   season   value 
1     Ben     fall       0   
2    Fred     fall       5     
3    Jose     fall       1   
4  Justin     fall       4   
5    Mike     fall       3 
6     Tom     fall       2  
7     Ben     spring     8
8    Fred     spring     0
9    Jose     spring     6
10 Justin     spring     9
11   Mike     spring    10
12    Tom     spring     7
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to perform all of those transformations in one step, but you can 'replace NAs in season with "spring"/"fall" and replace NAs in value with "0"' using `power_full_join()` from the [powerjoin](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/powerjoin) package, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(powerjoin)

#Data1
df1 <- data.frame(name = c("Jose","Tom","Mike","Justin","Fred"), 
                  season = c("fall", "fall", "fall","fall","fall"),
                  value = c("1","2","3","4","5"))
df1
#>     name season value
#> 1   Jose   fall     1
#> 2    Tom   fall     2
#> 3   Mike   fall     3
#> 4 Justin   fall     4
#> 5   Fred   fall     5

#Data2
df2 <- data.frame(name = c("Jose", "Tom", "Ben","Justin","Mike"), 
                  season = c("spring", "spring","spring","spring","spring"),
                  value = c("6","7","8","9","10"))
df2
#>     name season value
#> 1   Jose spring     6
#> 2    Tom spring     7
#> 3    Ben spring     8
#> 4 Justin spring     9
#> 5   Mike spring    10

dfcomb <- merge(df1, df2, by = "name", all = TRUE)

df1 %>%
  power_full_join(df2, by = c("name"), fill = list(season.x = "fall",
                                                   season.y = "spring",
                                                   value.x = "0",
                                                   value.y = "0")) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(name, season.x, season.y), names_repair = "unique") %>% # pivot_longer
  mutate(season = ifelse(name...4 == "value.x", # create a new column "season"
                         "fall", "spring")) %>%
  mutate(value = as.numeric(value)) %>% # convert "value" from character to numeric
  select("name" = name...1, season, value) %>% # select the columns of interest
  arrange(season, name) # arrange by "season"/"name" to get the desired output
#> New names:
#> • `name` -> `name...1`
#> • `name` -> `name...4`
#> # A tibble: 12 × 3
#>    name   season value
#>    <chr>  <chr>  <dbl>
#>  1 Ben    fall       0
#>  2 Fred   fall       5
#>  3 Jose   fall       1
#>  4 Justin fall       4
#>  5 Mike   fall       3
#>  6 Tom    fall       2
#>  7 Ben    spring     8
#>  8 Fred   spring     0
#>  9 Jose   spring     6
#> 10 Justin spring     9
#> 11 Mike   spring    10
#> 12 Tom    spring     7
```

You can also get your desired outcome using functions from the [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/), e.g.

```r
dfcomb %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(name, season.x, season.y),
               names_repair = "unique") %>% # pivot the dataset
  mutate(season = ifelse(name...4 == "value.x", # create a new column "season"
                         "fall", "spring")) %>%
  replace_na(list(value = "0")) %>% # replace NAs with zero in "value"
  mutate(value = as.numeric(value)) %>% # convert "value" from character to numeric
  select("name" = name...1, season, value) %>% # select the columns of interest
  arrange(season, name) # arrange by "season"/"name" to get the desired output
#> New names:
#> • `name` -> `name...1`
#> • `name` -> `name...4`
#> # A tibble: 12 × 3
#>    name   season value
#>    <chr>  <chr>  <dbl>
#>  1 Ben    fall       0
#>  2 Fred   fall       5
#>  3 Jose   fall       1
#>  4 Justin fall       4
#>  5 Mike   fall       3
#>  6 Tom    fall       2
#>  7 Ben    spring     8
#>  8 Fred   spring     0
#>  9 Jose   spring     6
#> 10 Justin spring     9
#> 11 Mike   spring    10
#> 12 Tom    spring     7
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>